# Передача массива в контроллер и после в медиатор

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mediatr

Всем привет. Столкнулся с трудностью. Передаю в контроллер массив объектов:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<List<FileImportResult>> CheckDataInSstu(List<CheckDataInSSTURequest> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await Mediator.Send(request, cancellationToken);
}
```

Если я в параметрах контроллера указывают что в него приходит список или массив, то у меня подчеркивается весь код начиная с `await`.

Ошибка такая:

> Не удается неявно преобразовать "object" в "List"

(полное имя `FileImportResult` в ошибке записано немного иначе, но в целом ссылается на него).

Request медиатра:

```
public class CheckDataInSSTURequest : IRequest<List<FileImportResult>>
{
    public string JsonData { get; set; }
    public string NameJoson { get; set; }
    public bool Encoded { get; set; }
}
```

И QueryHandler:

```
internal class CheckDataInSSTUQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<List<CheckDataInSSTURequest>, List<FileImportResult>>
{
    public async Task<List<FileImportResult>> Handle(List<CheckDataInSSTURequest> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

В QueryHandler также подсвечивается ошибка на имени класса:

> Тип CheckDataInSSTURequest не может быть использован как TRequest в универслальном методе IRequestHandler<>. Нет преобразования неявной ссылку CheckDataInSSTURequest  в FileImportResult

Почему так? Eсли убhать `List<>`, и оставить везде просто `CheckDataInSSTURequest`, то никаких ошибок нет, но так не годится.

Comment: Что мешает засунуть массив в класс и реквест делать одним объектом, а не массивом? Ни разу не видел, чтобы в медиатр отправляли массив чего-то

Comment: `IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>` принимает два параметра типа. `TRequest` должен реализовывать `IRequest`, по-этому вы никак не можете передать в качестве него `List<CheckDataInSSTURequest>`

Comment: есть ли причина, по которой нельзя изменить ваш запрос и хендлер на `IRequest<FileImportResult>` и `IRequestHandler<CheckDataInSSTURequest, FileImportResult>`,  а `return await Mediator.Send(request, cancellationToken)` превратить в цикл? Если вы считаете что такая причина есть, покажите полный код хендлера

Comment: @OwDafuq Да ничего не мешает. Не подумал о таком варианте. Спасибо - это помогло :)

Comment: Тогда оформите ответ сами, чтобы другим, кто столкнется с такой же проблемой, можно было посмотреть как избежать таких ошибок :)